# How do I make squares be on the same level as each other?

Tags: java, recursion, awt

**This is what my output is :**

[image]

**This is how I want it to be :**

[image]

```
public void drawSquare(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
{
    g.drawRect(x,y,size,size);
    if(size >2 && x < 1001 && y <= 200)
    {
        x+= 10+size;     
       // y = I know I'm supposed to modify y, but I'm lost on how to make it level out...
        size = size*3/4;
        drawSquare(g,x,y,size);
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try something like this: `int prevSize = size; size = (size * 3) / 4; y+= (prevSize - size);`.

Comment: `y += size/4` . Better use double to avoid rounding error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the y-axis points downward, therefore the tops of the squares are aligned. Instead, to keep the bottoms aligned, consider that the y coordinate for each square must be adjusted by the size difference to the previous square. What I mean is that if you look at any two squares, the square on the right needs to be moved downward by some amount, and that amount is equal to the difference in size between the two squares.

```
public void drawSquare(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
{
    g.drawRect(x,y,size,size);
    if(size >2 && x < 1001 && y <= 200)
    {
        x+= 10+size;     
        int newSize = size*3/4;
        y = y + size - newSize; // (size - newSize) is the difference
        size = newSize;
        drawSquare(g,x,y,size);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your modified code answer.....how is the new size going to be applied to the next square to be drawn? This is basically what I had already mentioned in a comment an hour before. ;)

Comment: Good point, I made an edit. This is the same as your solution (is there any other possible solution?), I just wanted to add more explanation.